# نحن (Nahnu) usage in the Ancient Near-East

Tags: arabic, surah

In my college classes, I am studying the Quran and I've noticed that the "We" pronoun used by Allah is typically seen as the "Royal We," but I cannot seem to find that sense of the word prior to the 11th century and further, I cannot find نحن (nahnu) to ever be used in the singular sense by contemporaries of Muhammed; especially in his cultural context. Even the Semitic relative Hebrew term נַחְנוּ (also pronounced nahnu), is always utilized in the plural. I was just hoping someone could help provide me with insight and resources in studying this (preferably works of antiquity written within a century of Muhammed.)

With my utmost respect, I thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Questions about language are off-topic.

However the use of a plural noun or pronoun to refer to a single entity is fairly normal. For example:

> قلنا يا ذا القرنين إما أن تعذب وإما أن تتخذ فيهم حسنا
>
> We said, "O Dhul-Qarnayn, either you punish [them] or else adopt among them [a way of] goodness."
>
> قال أما من ظلم فسوف نعذبه ثم يرد إلى ربه فيعذبه عذابا نكرا
>
> He said, "As for one who wrongs, we (meaning I) will punish him. Then he will be returned to his Lord, and He will punish him with a terrible punishment.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 18:86-87](https://quran.com/18/86-87?translations=20)</sup>

> إنا اتخذنا خاتما، ونقشنا فيه نقشا، فلا ينقش عليه أحد
>
> We (meaning I) have got a ring made and engraved a certain engraving on it so none of you should get such an engraving on his ring.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari 5874](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5874)</sup>